# Detecting the * keypress in wpf

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

I've tried checking for OEM 8 and if the keypressed is shift but this isn't working.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Key.OemMultiply for the numeric keypad

The other is Key.D8 and checking e.Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Shift

Pro-tip: put a breakpoint in your key handler to see for yourself what key you want to handle.